# Algorithm to build TNM stage from cTNM and pTNM variables

Tags: r, algorithm

I was wondering whether someone is aware of an R algorithm able to build TNM stage (I,II,III,IV) for cancer diseases using variables about cT, cN, cM, pT, pN, pM, ypTMM and version of TNM classification?

Answer (score 0):

Use case_when:

```
TNM = case_when(cT < 3 & cN == 0 & cM == 0 ~ 1,
          cM == 1 ~ 4)
```

...

Comment: Thanks! Maybe my question is unclear. I am capable to build the stage, what I am looking for is an algorithm. Each cancer site has its own staging system, depending on when the cancer was diagnosed etc. All of this is described in the TNM books but I was wondering if anyone had the courage to transcribe this huge amount of information into an algorithm.